# Make WebBrowser control work exactly like IE

Tags: windows-phone-8

I wish to make `WebBrowser` control used in my application for Windows Phone 8 work exactly like Internet Explorer. While testing my app, it works perfectly on IE but not on my `WebBrowser` Control. What are things I should consider to make them work same.

I checked the Browser Version from JS for both and its same.

**EDIT** : This is how my WebBrowser Element is defined

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webView"
    IsScriptEnabled="True"
    Grid.Row="0"
    IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
    ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
    NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
    Navigated="webView_Navigated"
    Navigating="webView_Navigating"
    SizeChanged="webView_SizeChanged"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="100">
</phone:WebBrowser>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should watch this : http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/WebBrowser_Control_Techniques_in_Windows_Phone Especially this : If you want to enable JavaScript (usually you want) in your web control you must set property IsScriptEnabled to true. Home this helps !

Comment: Yes I have IsScriptEnabled set to true and I have gone through the link earlier. Any other thing that can be missing?

Comment: Do you have an example of what is wrong in the webbrowser control ?

Comment: @MakanWG I have a fixed header and fixed footer on my WebPage and a scrollable region in between. When I open it in IE header and footer both remains on the screen and everything looks fine. But on WebBrowser control, Header stays and footer goes under `ApplicationBar`. I have resized my WebBrowser control for Application Bar. Stil having same problem

Comment: Can you post your xaml code ? Maybe a summary of your html/css too ? Not sure I will find the answer but it could help others.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution for your case?

Comment: @DacianMujdar Not a proper solution. I added extra empty space in WebPage equal to height of Application Bar. But first you can check what's you transparency value for ApplicationBar. It should not be set else the WebView will get hidden under it.